# Add one to a number stored in a digit array

Tags: java, arrays, string, character

Given a non-negative number represented as an array of digits, plus one to the number.

The digits are stored such that the most significant digit is at the head of the list.

#### Example:

Given [1,2,3] which represents 123, return [1,2,4].

Given [9,9,9] which represents 999, return [1,0,0,0].

My code is not working for the input [9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0]  the output comes as just [9]

Can anyone tell me why?

```
public class Solution {
    /**
    * @param digits a number represented as an array of digits
    * @return the result
    */
    public int[] plusOne(int[] digits) {
        // Write your code here
        float n = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < digits.length; i++) {
            n = n*10 + digits[i];
        }
        n++;
        String s = Float.toString(n);
        s = s.substring(0, s.indexOf("."));
        int l = s.length();
        int result[] = new int[l];
        for(int i = 0; i < l; i++) {
            result[i] = Integer.parseInt(Character.toString(s.charAt(i)));
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using a float to store an integer number?

Comment: This is look like school exercise. You teacher expect that you will work with array directly

Comment: @TimB because the number can be greater than the max integer value

Comment: Are you sure you aren't supposed to do this by operating on the incoming array? i.e. just start at the end, add 1. If it overflows set to 0 and add 1 to next, etc.

Comment: @talex this is coding exercise on lintcode

Comment: @SadiqHusainKhan In which case it won't fit correctly in a float either. You need long or BigInteger in that case.

Comment: Can you describe what you think your function is doing? because it does not make any sense.

Comment: I'd probably convert the input to a string directly using a `StringBuilder`, parse that to an int or long, add one and convert back.

Comment: @SadiqHusainKhan float isn't good for big numbers too because it will round your number and show it in scientific notation 1.23e45 which is probably happened in your case

Comment: @TimB if the input is something like this [9,9,9,9,9,9,9] then i'll have to swap all numbers in a new array. I thought my process is an alternative to this

Comment: Your process is horrible, honestly. So many steps to go wrong and you losing data in the conversions, using a lot of CPU and memory you don't need etc. This can all be done with 2? 3? lines in a single for loop.

Comment: @talex i didn't know that float rounds off a number. It could be that is what is happening in the test case

Comment: @TimB can you show how?

Comment: @Thomas I'll try what you said

Comment: you may want to read this post: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/43343/add-one-to-a-number-represented-as-an-array-of-digits

Comment: @SadiqHusainKhan I posted something, it's completely untested so you may need to do some tidying and debugging to get it to compile and run correctly. That will help you try and understand it rather than just copying it though ;) It came to a bit more than 3 lines but only because I was handling resizing the array and copying the data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the input [9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0], the value of `n` after this code:

> ```
> float n = 0;
> for(int i = 0; i < digits.length; i++) {
>     n = n*10 + digits[i];
> }
> n++;
> ```

... is 9.8765435E9. Then, you go on and take the substring of this until the decimal point, which is 9, so the result becomes 9.

It would work better if you changed the type of `n` from `float` to `long`,
and converted to string using `Long.toString`.

But this whole approach of creating `n`, adding 1, and then converting to String, and then converting to an array is awkward, error prone, and cannot work with larger arrays, as it becomes subject to integer overflow, unless you change the type of `n` to `BigInteger`. This solution would not pass in any tests or programming interviews.

Consider this alternative that is simpler, and will work with arbitrarily many digits (as permitted by array size) without worrying about integer overflow:

```
public int[] plusOne(int[] digits) {
    for (int i = digits.length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
        digits[i]++;
        if (digits[i] < 10) {
            return digits;
        }
        digits[i] = 0;
    }
    int[] result = new int[digits.length + 1];
    System.arraycopy(digits, 0, result, 1, digits.length);
    result[0] = 1;
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Your answer is the best among all of them because you provided the reason why my code was failing. Thanks for the alternative code too

Answer (score 1):

If you want to go your strange way you need to use `BigInt` instead of `float`

But normally this problem is solved by increment last digit and go to nex one in case of overflow.

Like that:

1. consider last digit
2. increment current digit
3. if it is `10` make change it to `0`, move one digit left and go to `2`.
   Check special case that no digit is left. In this case prepend `0` to your array
4. you have required result.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this is almost certainly what they have in mind:

```
int result = new int[digits.length+1]; // Result with room for 1 more digit
boolean carry = true; // Are we adding 1
for (int i=digits.length-1;i>0;i++) { // Loop from end of digits
   if (carry) {
       if (digits[i]==9) { // 9 goes to 0 and carries forwards
          result[i+1]=0;
       } else {
          result[i+1]=digits[i]+1; // Other values get incremented and carry goes
          carry=false;
       }
   } else {
      result[i+1]=digits[i];
   }
}

// If we still have a carry set the new first digit (otherwise it's already at 0.
if (carry) {
  result[0]=1;
}
```

Comment: This code always add digit. even if this isn't necessary

Comment: Where? It only adds if carry is true.

Comment: I mean resulting array always longer then input

Comment: Yes it will have an extra 0 at the start. That can be avoided if needed but I'll leave that for sadiq to do if it is a requirement since I already basically wrote his exercise for him. (Note that the value is correct even with a leading zero)

Comment: Now i will complain about spoon-feeding which is not appreciated on this site. There are people who always complain. It's me :)

Answer (score 0):

```
public int[] plusOne(int[] digits) {

    int n = digits.length;

    for(int i=n-1;i>=0;i--){
        if(digits[i]!=9){
            digits[i]+=1;
            return digits;
        }
        digits[i]=0;

    }
    int [] newDigits = new int [n+1];
    newDigits[0]=1;
    return newDigits;
}
```

Comment: Hi - generally code only answers aren't helpful. Can you explain why this code works, and how it is better/different to other solutions?

Comment: Lets start from the last digit

Case I.
1. if the  last digit is not equal to 9
eg: 144
then we will take last digit and add 1 to it and return
returned : 145

2. If the last digit is equal to 9
eg : 129 
then we will make that 9 to 0 and loop through to digit left to it
returned : 130


3. if all the digits are 9 
eg :999
then lets make all 9 to 0 and create a new array with digits.lenth+1 
where all default elements are 0.
and put 1 to first element
it will be 1000 

lets me know if it is not clear

Answer (score 0):

```
public ArrayList<Integer> plusOne(ArrayList<Integer> A) {
       // ArrayList<Integer> abc= new ArrayList<>();
        if(A.get(0)==0){
            A.remove(0);
        }

        if(A.get(A.size()-1)<9){
            A.add(A.size()-1, A.get(A.size()-1)+1);
            A.remove(A.size()-1);
            return A;
        }
        int end= A.size()-1;
       while(A.get(end)== 9){
           A.add(end,0);
           A.remove(end+1);
          end=end-1;
           if(A.get(end)<9) {
               A.add(end, A.get(end) + 1);
               A.remove(end +1);
           }
       }
        return A;
    }
```